# How do I merge 2 twig templates

Tags: node.js, twig, twig.js

Is there a possibility or workaround how to merge 2 twig templates? (NOT `render`!)

To give more context, let's assume I have `base.twig`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and a child `content.twig`:

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Hello {{ username }}</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

**Expected result:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Hello {{ username }}</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't think this will be possible, at the one hand you do want to render the `extends` tag, but you don't want to render `variables`?

Comment: on a high level - yes (extends, include, etc.)

Comment: This is a longshot, but what about setting `{{ username }}` as value for `username`? Do note though you wouldn't not be able to parse dynamic includes then

Comment: As well as loops and all the template engine related features, so it's not suitable